# Openshift Haproxy Layer 7 Wrong Status

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I have an application on Openshift which has been working fine for months and suddenly has gone 503. Haproxy Status says 
Layer 7 Wrong Status Internal Server Error

I have checked the logs and there is no mention of anything particular. I have check the usage quota and it's well below the 1024M limit. I have restarted the app many times with no success.
I have checked haproxy.cfg and the root gear address is correct.

How can this happen? It seems all is lost an there is no documentation about it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically that error means that your application on your gears (behind the haproxy) is not reachable.  Can you verify that you have something listening on the root context (/) of your application?  It might also help to see the actual logs, along with your application url.

Comment: Hi there Corey. If by listening you mean
> listen express 127.2.221.130:8080
   > cookie GEAR insert indirect nocache
  >  option httpchk GET /
   > balance leastconn
   > server local-gear 127.2.221.129:8080 check fall 2 rise 3 inter >2000 cookie local-xxxx

(The gear number is correct), then it should be fine.

Comment: The access and error logs are empty:

This is the error log after app-tidy:


[Fri Feb 28 10:12:58 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c1,c445
[Fri Feb 28 10:12:58 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Feb 28 10:12:58 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Feb 28 10:12:58 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Actually, it seem more a mysql cartridge problem similar to this:

[link] (https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127391-111)

I get "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on [...]"
when I type mysql from a ssh session.

Please help!!! @coreydeveloper

Comment: Not connecting to mysql could be causing an error with your application that is causing the haproxy not to be able to reach it, have you tried just stopping/starting mysql? What do your mysql logs say?

Comment: I have restarted many times.

The error log is meaningless to me:

140228 13:45:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/XXX/mysql/data/
140228 13:45:18  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
140228 13:45:18  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140228 13:45:18  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
140228 13:45:18 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140228 13:45:18 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/XXX/mysql//socket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution

Comment: have you ssh'd to your mysql gear and do a ps -ef and make sure it's running?  rhc app show <appname> --gears will show all the gears in your scaled application, and you can ssh to any of them

Comment: UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
5277     383242 383198  0 16:36 ?        00:00:00 sshd: 52adca69e0b8cd6f62000435@pts/1
5277     383243 383242  2 16:36 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash --init-file /usr/bin/rhcsh -i
5277     383728 383243  0 16:36 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef
5277     439298      1  0 13:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /var/lib/openshift/52adca69e0b8cd6f62000435/mysql/bin/control res
5277     439304 439298  0 13:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh

Comment: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/var/lib/openshift/52adca69e0b
5277     439453 439304  0 13:45 ?        00:00:04 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/var/lib/openshift/52adca69e0b8cd6f6200

is it running?

Comment: Can you connect to the mysql server from THAT gear? the mysql gear?

Comment: yes I can. But it's because now SUDDENLY the application is up and running after 48hours of despair. It doesn't make any sense, I haven't touched a thing. I can also connect from my app gear. It really doesn't make any sense. Have you done something?

Comment: As far as I know we did not do anything to it.

Comment: Did you find any resolutions to this issue?